What is the difference between 노동자 vs 근로자? I'm also a bit confused with their meanings
노동자 is listed as a manual/physical laborer in HTSK.
When I searched it up, it said that this word could be used for any worker, e.g office worker, store worker. So is 노동자 mainly used for a physical labourer or just any worker in general?
Also, is 근로자 also just used for any worker in general? What's the difference between 노동자 vs 근로자 vs 종업원?

노동자 is the traditional term for "laborer".  It can mean manual laborer in a narrow context but it can also refer to any worker who does work by exerting themselves.
근로자 is a less frequently used term that just means "worker".  Since 노동자 has acquired the connotation of laborer as someone who fights the management (as in 노동 운동 = labor movement), governments and other organizations often want to avoid those political overtones and 근로자 fills this need nicely.  For instance, 근로자의 날 is Worker's Day.  It is a textbook-like term mostly used in very formal contexts.
There are numerous words describing work and job.  I'll list some common ones.
Common verbs.

일하다 = to work (most general and widely used term).
노동하다 = to labor. 육체노동자 = blue color worker. 정신노동자 = white color worker.
근무하다 = to be on duty at work.  근무지 = workplace. 근무시간 = work hours.
작업하다 = to work on a task.  현장 작업자 = workers on scene.

General terms for "employed worker".

종업원 = worker/employee (sometimes implies employment status)
직원 = same, but more vague, a little like "clerk" or "person on hand".
사원 = an employee of a private workplace.  More formal than 종업원 or 직원.
(All three are common terms describing employees of a workplace)

Terms for "worker" in general (and typically more formal).

노동자 = worker or laborer.  Makes compound words like 부두 노동자 (dock laborer).
근무자 = person on duty.
작업자 = person working on a (well defined) task.
인력 = workforce.
관리자 = manager or caretaker.
노무자 = workers doing physical work.
일꾼 = similar to 노무자 but more informal (and somewhat disparaging).

